# undefined local variable or method `current_user' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, device, cancan

I'm getting the

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user` error for
```

caused by the following code in my view

```
<% if can? :update, Project %>
  <span class="admin">
    <%= link_to 'Nieuw Project', new_project_path %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

When I remove the code the page renders correctly.

CanCan code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)   
    user ||= User.new

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, Post
      can :manage, Project
      can :manage, Page
      can :manage, Comment
      can :manage, User
    else
      can :read, :all
      cannot :read, User      
      can :create, Comment      
    end
  end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, #:registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  def admin?
    self.id
  end
end
```

specs of my app

> - rails 3.0.3
> - devise 1.5.3
> - devise invitable  0.6.0
> - cancan 1.6.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are falling to this little detail about cancan and devise. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/changing-defaults
Cancan expects a `current_user` method to be in your controller. Check to see if this exists.